# Question about NYPD regulations

Tags: new-york-state, police

I have heard this from 3 people now and I am trying to find the law being used.

In the NYC Transit system, if a party is even questioned by NYPD (something happens where they call in your drivers license), if said person has received 2 or more tickets in the system, whether paid/case closed or not, that party is going to the pokie for processing.

Without anything pending in the courts, what law are they using that allows them to detain someone?

It's some sort of indexing system.
I don't see how it could be legal either.

Comment: In NYC Transit??

Comment: yes, as indicated in the post.

Comment: Okay, just making sure, because you mentioned a driver license, that you didn't mean something like MTA Bridges and Tunnels.

Comment: In NYC, you can be jailed for not having ID, anywhere in the city.

Comment: @NIX: Citation needed.

Comment: But they will justify it with a ticket for breathing illegally.